# How to set date display format for jQuery datepicker?

Tags: 7, javascript, datetime

I am using the standard jQuery datepicker in Drupal 7 and I would like to change how it saves and displays dates. Instead of displaying 10/11/2013, I would like it to display as November 10, 2013 for clarity. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change how the datepicker displays in your content entry form, go to Structure > Content types > *YourType* > Manage fields > *YourField*. Expand the section labeled, "MORE SETTINGS AND VALUES", then select the desired date format from the "Date entry options" select list.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this

```
 $(function(){
        $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).bind("change",function(){
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
            $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 9 you can create the new custom library and attach it to some elements. Example of library code :

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.FAJqueryUiDatepickerLocale = {
    attach: function attach(context, settings) {
      // console.log(drupalSettings);
      $.datepicker.regional['drupal-locale'] = $.extend({
        dateFormat: Drupal.t('dd/mm/yy'),
      }, drupalSettings.jquery.ui.datepicker);
      $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['drupal-locale']);
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

Works fine for me.